# Why is Jquery plugin not applying to inner tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I am using 2 jQuery plugins, one for tabs and another to slide images within my tabs. Currently I have 2 tabs. jQuery for the first tab works fine but when I click on the next tab it dosent work. The elements are present in the second tab as well, but the classes are not toggled from hidden to visible.

I am using these two plugins
[For My tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs)
[For Sliding images inside each Tab](http://bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel)

Here Goes my Code :-

```
<div class="demo" style="display: inline-block;">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1" > <?php echo $categoryName ?> </a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2" > <?php echo $categoryName ?> </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <div id="waterwheel-carousel-flat1">
                <div class="carousel-controls">
                    <div class="carousel-prev"><a href="#">&lt; previous</a></div>
                    <div class="carousel-next"><a href="#">&gt; next</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-images">
                    <a href=<?php echo $productLink ?> ><img src= <?php echo $imageLink ?> alt= <?php echo $productName ?>/> </a> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-2">
            <div id="waterwheel-carousel-flat">
                <div class="carousel-controls">
                    <div class="carousel-prev"><a href="#">&lt; previous</a></div>
                    <div class="carousel-next"><a href="#">&gt; next</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-images">
                    <a href=<?php echo $productLink ?> ><img src= <?php echo $imageLink ?> alt= <?php echo $productName ?>/> </a> 
                    <?php }  ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Script for Sliding Images Inside Tabs Goes here:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jq = $.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function () {
    jq("#waterwheel-carousel-default").waterwheelCarousel();

    jq("#waterwheel-carousel-higharch").waterwheelCarousel({
        startingWaveSeparation: -90,
        waveSeparationFactor: .7,
        centerOffset: 10,
        startingItemSeparation: 120,
        itemSeparationFactor: .9,
        itemDecreaseFactor: .75
    });

    jq("#waterwheel-carousel-horizon").waterwheelCarousel({
        startingWaveSeparation: 0,
        centerOffset: 30,
        startingItemSeparation: 150,
        itemSeparationFactor: .7,
        itemDecreaseFactor: .75,
        opacityDecreaseFactor: 1,
        autoPlay: 1500
    });

    jq("#waterwheel-carousel-flat").waterwheelCarousel({
        itemSeparationFactor: 1,
        itemDecreaseFactor: 1,
        waveSeparationFactor: 1,
        startingWaveSeparation: 0,
        startingItemSeparation: 280,
        centerOffset: 10,
        opacityDecreaseFactor: .3,
        autoPlay: 3000,
        edgeReaction: 'reverse'
    });

    jq("#waterwheel-carousel-vertical").waterwheelCarousel({
        orientation: 'vertical',
        startingItemSeparation: 100,
        startingWaveSeparation: 40,
        autoPlay: 2000
    });


  });
</script>
```

Here Is My Generated Html Code

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">



    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-1"> Lovely new arrivals </a></li>


    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-2"> Designer Collection </a></li>



</ul>

<div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    <div id="waterwheel-carousel-flat">
      <div class="carousel-controls">
        <div class="carousel-prev"><a href="#">&lt; previous</a></div>
        <div class="carousel-next"><a href="#">&gt; next</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-images" style="position: relative;">



          <a href="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/index.php/gold-gilt-button-bed.html"><img bed="" button="" gilt="" alt="Gold" src="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/161x161/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/u/sub-cat-pro-01_03_2.jpg" style="display: inline; left: 119.5px; top: 10px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 5; opacity: 0.3; width: 161px; height: 161px;" class=""> </a> 

          <a href="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/index.php/willows-shell-carved-bed-silver-1.html"><img silver1="" -="" bed="" carved="" shell="" alt="Willows" src="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/161x161/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/u/sub-cat-pro-01_03_3.jpg" style="display: inline; left: 399.5px; top: 10px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 6; opacity: 1; width: 161px; height: 161px;" class="active"> </a> 

          <a href="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/index.php/classical-white-5ft-rococo-bed-1.html"><img bed="" rococo="" 5ft="" white="" alt="Classical" src="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/161x161/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/u/sub-cat-pro-01_03_4.jpg" style="display: inline; left: 679.5px; top: 10px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 5; opacity: 0.3; width: 161px; height: 161px;" class=""> </a> 

          <a href="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/index.php/bed.html"><img alt="Bed/" src="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/161x161/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg" style="display: inline; left: 959.5px; top: 10px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 4; opacity: 0.09; width: 161px; height: 161px;" class=""> </a> 

          <a href="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/index.php/green-bed.html"><img bed="" alt="Green" src="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/161x161/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/o/cooper_black_bed.jpg" style="display: inline; left: 1239.5px; top: 10px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 3; opacity: 0.027; width: 161px; height: 161px;" class=""> </a> 
                                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
    <div id="waterwheel-carousel-flat1">
      <div class="carousel-controls">
        <div class="carousel-prev"><a href="#">&lt; previous</a></div>
        <div class="carousel-next"><a href="#">&gt; next</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-images">



          <a href="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/index.php/product-4.html"><img silver="" -="" bed="" carved="" shell="" alt="Willows" src="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/161x161/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/k/i/kingsley-bate-rectangular-dining-set-furniture.jpg"> </a> 

          <a href="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/index.php/gold-gilt-button-bed.html"><img bed="" button="" gilt="" alt="Gold" src="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/161x161/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/u/sub-cat-pro-01_03_2.jpg"> </a> 

          <a href="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/index.php/willows-shell-carved-bed-silver-1.html"><img silver1="" -="" bed="" carved="" shell="" alt="Willows" src="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/161x161/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/u/sub-cat-pro-01_03_3.jpg"> </a> 

          <a href="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/index.php/classical-white-5ft-rococo-bed-1.html"><img bed="" rococo="" 5ft="" white="" alt="Classical" src="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/161x161/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/u/sub-cat-pro-01_03_4.jpg"> </a> 

          <a href="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/index.php/green-bed.html"><img bed="" alt="Green" src="http://127.0.0.1/sweetpea/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/161x161/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/o/cooper_black_bed.jpg"> </a> 
                                </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? The tab or the sliding image plugin? Could you please post the jQuery you've written. Also, you should really wrap the values of your attributes in quotes, eg. `href="<?php echo $productLink ?>"`

Comment: You also appear to have a rogue `<?php }  ?>` in yor code, although I don't believe that is the cause of your problem.

Comment: When I Click On the Tab I expect the images with my image sliding script and Css as i am getting in for the first tab. But I am not able to see effects on my 2nd tab

Comment: Your script doesn't seem to do anything with `waterwheel-carousel-flat1`. Is this right? I'd say that was the problem but that looks like it is on the working tab...

Comment: Yes @Chris, But isishka Said He needs my Script. U know this is the script that doesnt get loaded on my both tabs, in fact first one applies the script however the second one fails to load this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't work because of that:

```
<div id="waterwheel-carousel-flat">
....
<div id="waterwheel-carousel-flat">
```

the id must be unique within a document

---

I hope now you can see why **""** (quotes) - are important by specifying html attributes (look at your images)

the problem is - you've renamed your div, but not initialized it, add initialization for #waterwheel-carousel-flat1

---

```
jq("#waterwheel-carousel-flat,#waterwheel-carousel-flat1").waterwheelCarousel({
  ... 
});
```

---

OR use class attribute instead of id:

**js init**:

```
jq(".waterwheel-carousel-flat").waterwheelCarousel({
  ... 
});
```

**html**:

```
<div class="waterwheel-carousel-flat">
...
<div class="waterwheel-carousel-flat">
```

Comment: and there are quots here in <a href=_"_<?php echo $productLink ?>_"_ >, and inside img tag ?

Comment: If That ll be The Cause Then None Of The Tabs Should Have Worked... But My First Tab Is working fine.the problem is with the 2nd tab

Comment: Thanks For Ur response i ve added the script in my question

Comment: and where is your initialization for  jq("#waterwheel-carousel-flat1").waterwheelCarousel() ?

Comment: please, show _generated_ html (from browser source) and place where you include js on your page

Comment: Thanks for ur response, Yes That may Be The Problem, So how can I add initialization for #waterwheel-carousel-flat1 ?

Comment: Thanks A Lot, U Saved My Another Day, That was Great... I do Accept The Answer And Add U +10